# Temp table in PDW disappears after 1st execution

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, temp-tables

I am connecting to a PDW (Parallel Data Warehouse) 2012 database using a Visual Studio 2008 Server Explorer Data Connection and related Query Designer (not an ideal combo I know).

If I run all three statements below at once, I get results:

```
    create table #diagnosis_condition (dx_code varchar(4), condition_code char(3)) WITH (LOCATION = USER_DB)
    insert into #diagnosis_condition (dx_code,condition_code) values ('J45','AST')
    SELECT * FROM #diagnosis_condition

    Results: J45    AST
```

If after this I delete the "create" and "insert" lines from my query window and re-execute the "select", I get an error:

```
SQL Execution Error.   
Executed SQL statement: SELECT * FROM [#diagnosis_condition]  
Error Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider  
Error Message: Invalid object name '#diagnosis_condition'.
```

If I do the same thing in SQL Server Management Studio with a non-PDW database connection, the temp table persists and I get the same results again.

Why does my Visual Studio PDW connection behave differently? Is this a PDW issue or a Visual Studio Query Designer issue or a user error?? I want to persist the temp table (with more rows of course) so I can run my subsequent code in chunks without recreating the table every time. I’m not new to SSMS but am new to PDW and VS so I may be missing the obvious. Thanks for any help!

Comment: That is because a temp table is dropped when the connection that creates it is closed. In other words, your code is closing the connection (as it should) which also drops the temp table. You can do this in SSMS because the temp table persists while the current connection is open (in SSMS each tab has its own connection).

Comment: Expanding on what Sean has already mention, if you want to be able to access temp tables from multiple connections , you can use Global temp tables prefixed with double pound sign e.g `##diagnosis_condition` . Mind you this will error out if two people simultaneously make a call to a procedure which is making use of a Global temp table.

Comment: @SeanLange: "your code is closing the connection (as it should) which#also drops the temp table" - this appears to explain the behavior, thank you. The fact that SSMS doesn't do this within a tab had led me to assume that persistence was the normal behavior but perhaps (sigh) it is the other way around.

Comment: @M.Ali: I appreciate the thought but per this link: http://binaryworld.net/blogs/how-to-create-temp-table-on-pdw-parallel-data-warehouse/
“Global Temp tables not supported in PDW” so I had already eliminated this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a copy of VS2008 handy, but in VS2013 there is a setting under Options-> Sql Server Tools -> Transact-SQL Editor -> Query Execution -> Advanced that says `Disconnect after the query executes`.

I'll bet your VS installation has its equivalent option set.

Comment: Well that makes sense, but I've gone thru everything under Tools->Options->Database Tools in VS2008 and cannot find this setting. Web search did not turn up anything either, so I guess I have to assume I cannot control this within VS2008. If you find otherwise please let me know! Thanks.